# Problemas con una relación Many to Many en Django

Tags: django

Soy nuevo en Django y estoy tratando de hacer un ticket sencillo de compra que me está llevando por calle de la amargura xD

Intento relacionar a 1 solo comprador con varios productos, pero me está siendo imposible. Gracias de antemano.

Siempre me arroja errores como el siguiente "AttributeError at /admin/ticket/venta/add/
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'precio'
Request Method: POST"

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
class Comprador(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + ' | ' + self.email


class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Producto: {self.nombre} | Precio: {str(self.precio)} | \
         Cantidad: {str(self.cantidad)}'


    class Venta(models.Model):
        comprador = models.ForeignKey(Comprador, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        producto = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, related_name='productos')
        pagado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        enviado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        fecha_pedido = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)
    
        @property
        def importe_total(self):
            return self.producto.precio * self.producto.cantidad
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'Comprador: {self.comprador} | Fecha pedido {self.fecha_pedido} ' \
                   f' Importe total: {str(self.importe_total)}'
```

Comment: En la respuesta te comenté que te iva a dejar el enlace a la documentación de django para si querías profundizar pero se me pasó, aqui te dejo el enlace: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Mil gracias. Muy amable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estuve mirando tu código, te faltan algunos detalles, no te preocupes, creo que con lo siguiente vas a encaminarte:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Este código es el claro ejemplo de una sencilla relación de muchos a muchos con propiedades adicionales en la tabla intermedia. Deves concentrarte en esta línea de código:

```
members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
```

Esta línea relaciona de muchos a muchos el modelo Group con el modelo Persona mediante la tabla Membership definida por la propiedad "through". Espero que esto te sea de ayuda, de todas formas te dejo aki el enlace de este ejemplo en la documentación de django. Saludos.

Comment: Si te surge alguna duda no dudes en dejarme un comentario

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda! Lo probaré en cuanto pueda y si no funciona lo comentaré! De nuevo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay que registrar la clase Membership en admin.py ?
Lo hice pero igualmente desde el Administrador de Django, al cargar un grupo no me permite cargar las personas asociadas.
Es posible esto usando tabla intermedia con trough ? Antes cuando no usaba el trough sí podía.